# How to compare a single value to an array using XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I want to compare a single value if it's existing to an array. I have an XML input file:

```
<wd:Report_Entry
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CRI_-_INTSG031_CM_011_-_PUBBS_HSA_Customer_Invoice">
    <wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group>
        <wd:pubbsType>1</wd:pubbsType>
        <wd:pubbsService>A+</wd:pubbsService>
        <wd:validFrom>2019-08-01</wd:validFrom>
        <wd:validTo>2100-01-01</wd:validTo>
        <wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_From_Date>2019-08-01</wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_From_Date>
        <wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date>2100-01-01</wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date>
    </wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group>
    <wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group>
        <wd:pubbsType>1</wd:pubbsType>
        <wd:pubbsService>A-</wd:pubbsService>
        <wd:validFrom>2019-08-01</wd:validFrom>
        <wd:validTo>2100-01-01</wd:validTo>
        <wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_From_Date>2019-08-01</wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_From_Date>
        <wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date>2100-01-01</wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date>
    </wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group>
    <wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group>
        <wd:pubbsType>FMDAUTOPSY</wd:pubbsType>
        <wd:pubbsService>FMDAUTOPSY</wd:pubbsService>
        <wd:validFrom>2020-02-02</wd:validFrom>
        <wd:validTo>2020-02-01</wd:validTo>
        <wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_From_Date>2020-02-01</wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_From_Date>
        <wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date>2100-01-01</wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date>
    </wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group>
    <wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group>
        <wd:pubbsType>FMDBODYSTOR</wd:pubbsType>
        <wd:pubbsService>FMDBODYSTOR</wd:pubbsService>
        <wd:validFrom>2020-01-01</wd:validFrom>
        <wd:validTo>2020-01-31</wd:validTo>
        <wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_From_Date>2020-01-01</wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_From_Date>
        <wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date>2020-01-31</wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date>
    </wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group>
 <wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
        <wd:referenceID>CUSTOMER_INVOICE_LINE-6-46</wd:referenceID>
        <wd:Unit_Cost>0</wd:Unit_Cost>
        <wd:Quantity>0</wd:Quantity>
        <wd:Calculated_Tax_Amount>0</wd:Calculated_Tax_Amount>
        <wd:CFI_AC_Merchandise_Amount>100</wd:CFI_AC_Merchandise_Amount>
        <wd:Line_Item_Description>LINE ITEM DESC</wd:Line_Item_Description>
        <wd:Line_Memo>LINE MEMO</wd:Line_Memo>
        <wd:Transaction_Tax_Amount>0</wd:Transaction_Tax_Amount>
        <wd:CFI_LRV_Sales_Item_Reference_ID>FMDAUTOPSY</wd:CFI_LRV_Sales_Item_Reference_ID>
    </wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
    <wd:CFI_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Current_Date>2020-02-16</wd:CFI_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Current_Date>
</wd:Report_Entry>
```

I want to know if the `wd:CFI_LRV_Sales_Item_Reference_ID` value is equal to `wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group/wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group/wd:pubbsService` and `wd:CFI_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Current_Date` is greater than `wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date` and then just return a string value true if there is. I have a code like this but this doesn't work because I'm comparing a value to an object that has multiple values. Not sure how to do compare single value to an array using *xslt* 2 or 3.. Appreciate the help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CRI_-_INTSG031_CM_011_-_PUBBS_HSA_Customer_Invoice"
    xmlns:d9="urn:this-stylesheet">

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PUBBS>      


            <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry/wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group">
                <xsl:if test="wd:CFI_LRV_Sales_Item_Reference_ID != ''">
                    <xsl:for-each select="../wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group">
                        <xsl:if test="../wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group/wd:pubbsService != '' 
                            and wd:CFI_LRV_Sales_Item_Reference_ID = ../wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group/wd:pubbsService
                            and xs:date(../wd:CFI_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Current_Date) &gt; xs:date(../wd:CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group/wd:CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date)
                            ">    
                            <HASINVALIDSALESITEM>
                                <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
                            </HASINVALIDSALESITEM>   
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:if>  
            </xsl:for-each>
    </PUBBS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: First of all, while XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 has an array data type, that is an extension to the previous XSLT 2 data model to deal with JSON arrays and to have a nestable, lightweight data structure when not using XML; your question shows XML data, so I don't see how you would encounter any arrays there. As for your existing code, when it doesn't work, which error exactly do you get? Or which wrong output do you get, which is the exact result you want for the show input sample?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to simplify the code by using `xpath-default-namespace` and by using templates; I have also assumed the two values you want to compare the two details of the various `CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group` to only exist once in the input document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/CRI_-_INTSG031_CM_011_-_PUBBS_HSA_Customer_Invoice"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <PUBBS>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group"/>
      </PUBBS>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group[xs:date(//CFI_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Current_Date) > xs:date(CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date)
                       and
                       //CFI_LRV_Sales_Item_Reference_ID = pubbsService]">
     <HASINVALIDSALESITEM>true</HASINVALIDSALESITEM> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1ym that gives an empty `<PUBBS/>`, which seems the right result as the only `CFI_ARI_PUBBS_HSA_group` with `pubbsService` having the value `FMDAUTOPSY` has a `CF_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Valid_To_Date` of `2100-01-01` and the `CFI_FD_PUBBS_HSA_Current_Date` with the value `2020-02-16` is not greater than that.

It is not quite clear whether you want a single output of `HASINVALIDSALESITEM` even if there are several but the code could obviously adapted.